# Robots.txt and Regular Expressions

Tags: robots.txt, web-crawlers

If I place a regular expression in robots.txt will it be readable for the web crawlers?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, the robots.txt syntax only supports wildcards, and not regular expressions. See here for a good discussion of the syntax: http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html.

Comment: Wildcards are **not** supported by the [original robots.txt specification](http://www.robotstxt.org/orig.html).

Answer (score 6):

While it's not part of the standard robots.txt protocol (and therefore not globally recognized), Google and Bing both support LIMITED pattern matching.

For example:

```
User-agent: Googlebot
Disallow: /private*/
```

Will block Googlebot from any directory beginning with "private".  Currently, Googlebot supports `*` and `$` (end of string).

Details on Googlebot's pattern matching: http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=156449

Comment: Note that `Disallow: /private*/` does not block "any directory", but any URLs whose **path** *begins* with this string.